# Reading and running Powershell file from text

Tags: file, text, powershell

Right now, I'm trying to use a Powershell script to read through a text file and execute all of the Powershell scripts mentioned in it, but I can't get any results.  I've tried specifying it this way:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock{powershell.exe -noexit $val} -name $jobnum
```

and this way:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock{$val}
```

(`$val` is the value of the line of text)
but it doesn't run the script that's written on that line.

And I've tried this way:

```
Start-Job -FilePath($val) -name $jobnum
```

But I get this error:

> `Start-Job` : Only PowerShell script files are allowed for `FilePath` parameter. Specify a file with `.ps1` extension.

Even though the value of `$val` is a legitimate path to a file with `ps1` extension!

My text lines look like this: `C:\Users\me\Desktop\notepad.ps1`

How do I get my Powershell script to read in text and run the `ps1` scripts that have a path given in the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {powershell.exe -noexit $val} -name $jobnum
```

you need to specify `-ArgumentList` parameter like this:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {param($v) .. your command using $v} -name $jobnum -argumentlist $val
```

Otherwise the `$value` is not known to the job.

Comment: Thanks!  I came back to the program this morning, needing to change it so it could run any type of script, and your answer was a huge time saver.

Comment: Another question: why doesn't this work for lines of text that work with variables, like this value of $val:

$env:the = 50
shouldn't it create the environmental variable the and set it equal to 50?

Comment: If you set `$env:the=50`, it correctly sets the variable in your powershell session. However, `Start-Job` creates a *new process* with its own set of variables. Check this using e.g. ProcessExplorer (from former SysInternals).

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, the problem was because I was doing -FilePath($val) instead of -FilePath $val.